# Pointer class added to User class that would retrieve on getCurrentUser()

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have added a new column in my `User` class which points to the `Locations` class. Is there a way to `.include(...)` it so that I have the location object available after calling `ParseUser.getCurrentUser()` ?

I could just make my own query but is there a way to change the default query it uses to retrieve the user to make it retrieve the object as well ... by default?

I am able to `put()` the location object in the user, but it will not retrieve it automatically (include it in the query by default.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer would be no because the actual query is executed in [NetworkUserController](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android/blob/0c3009afd0070fc7867f94d3a11f38195382a27d/Parse/src/main/java/com/parse/NetworkUserController.java) which has package visibility so you are not able to change its behavior.